# Spark: Grouping by Key, Mapping over Partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using spark 2.3.1.

I'm struggling to solve the following problem. I have data that comes as Pair(Key, Data). However due to the nature of what i need to do on the data, I need to run a map partition. That's because i need to instantiate an object that is not serializable, within each partition to perform the transformation i need to do.

For performance reason, I'd like that each partition just contain Data for a specific key.

In a sense I want to GroupByKey, and map over those group ? However, Mapping over a group is not equal to mapping over a partition. From the experience i have run, multiple group can be within the same partition.

Running the following code shows it.

```
partioneddf.rdd.groupBy(r => r(2).asInstanceOf[Long]).foreachPartition { it =>   {
    while (it.hasNext) {
      println(it.next._2.toString)
    };
    println("\n===\n")   }}
```

This gives me results that looks like that

> ===
>
> CompactBuffer([United States,Cuba,478]) CompactBuffer([French
>   Polynesia,United States,43], [United States,Martinique,43],
>   [Uruguay,United States,43]) CompactBuffer([United
>   States,Guatemala,318]) CompactBuffer([Luxembourg,United States,155])
>
> ===
>
> CompactBuffer([Peru,United States,279]) CompactBuffer([United
>   States,Austria,63], [United States,Guyana,63])
>   CompactBuffer([Ireland,United States,335])
>   CompactBuffer([Bermuda,United States,183]) CompactBuffer([United
>   States,Mexico,7187])
>
> ===
>
> ===
>
> CompactBuffer([Paraguay,United States,60])
>   CompactBuffer([France,United States,935]) CompactBuffer([United
>   States,Palau,31]) CompactBuffer([United States,Jordan,44],
>   [Jordan,United States,44], [Martinique,United States,44])
>
> ===

Which is totally not what I want. I would like that there is only one group per partition and map over that group using mapPartition.

Is that even feasible in spark ? I check around the API and could not come with a method. Maybe I am think the problem the wrong way.

Please, any suggestion or advise ?

**EDIT1:**

Reflecting on it,  I came to the conclusion that if things are grouped in each partition, then it is fine, but at least i would like to have "big groups" per partition instead of having my group spread all over the partitions that I have.

In a sense what I am saying is that I would like to have as much element of a group co-located in the same partition.

Then i can map over the partition processing group by group, maybe batching a little per group given the nature of the operation I need to do.

So relaxing the constraints, the question becomes, how can I set spark such that, records of the same group, that is, that share the same key, are as much as possible colocated in the same partition.

Comment: U have to update with: -  the sample input data of your data frame, its schema, and desired output. As your question, we dont know how to determine 2 rows is in the same group.

Comment: Anyway, in case of you need to do a  transformation using a non- serializable object. You can init that object in each executor instead of initalizing it on driver and serialize it to the executors.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The second point is in my requirements already. I am not sure to understand your first comment. can you explain ?

Comment: Could you please post the sample input data of your data frame, its schema, and desired output